# Dependence of $\tt n$ in $\tt fft(data,n)$ in auto correlation of data

Tags: image-processing, fft, autocorrelation

The followings are results of autocorrelation of an 'image'(1*) (subplot 221) using `xcorr`, `n` point `fft`, and `2n-1` point `fft`. I observe that I get different results. Why does it happen?

PS: result at subplot 223 is the expected image.

(1*) In fact it is identified as 'integrated image' in the paper doi:10.1038/nature11578 by Dr. Jacopo Bertolotti, which can not be considered as a general image that has both magnitude and phase information.

[image: Image and its autocorrelations]

Answer (score 1):

Doing an $N \times M$ point FFT for that sized image to calculate the autocorrelation will result in [time-aliasing](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Example_2_Time_Domain.html).

To multiply two signals of length $N$ in the frequency domain, the FFT length must be $2N-1$.